# partition mysql table by hour basis

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-indexes

My Example table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_1 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  createdAt datetime NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I'm looking to create a partition on an hourly basis since each hour there will be around 4 million records are saved, I would like to drop the partition after some processing. maximum 5 partitions will be available at a time.

As a starting step tried creating partition

```
alter table TEST_1 partition by range(createdAt)(
    PARTITION pmin values less than ('2021-11-17 08:00:00'),
    PARTITION p2020111709 values less than ('2020-11-17 09:00:00'),
    PARTITION p2020111710 values less than ('2020-11-17 10:00:00'),
    PARTITION p2020111711 values less than ('2020-11-17 11:00:00'),
    PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
)
```

but it throws error saying

> Error Code: 1697. VALUES value for partition 'pmin' must have type INT

using range columns it throws error as

> Error Code: 1493. VALUES LESS THAN value must be strictly increasing for each partition

I'm not sure how to move forward

Comment: You must: (1) change the datatype for `createdAt` from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP (2) create primary key which includes this column (3) use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdAt)` as partitioning expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution:  In less than 2 years, `id INT` will overflow.

Is there anything else in the table?  If so, why even have `id`?

What do you do with a list of 20M "names"?  And there can be duplicates.

There are other syntax options:

```
⚈  PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(DATETIME) (5.5.0)
⚈  PARTITION BY RANGE(TIMESTAMP) (version 5.5.15 / 5.6.3)
⚈  PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_SECONDS()) (5.6.0)
```

The first of those is probably closest to what you have.  Just insert  `COLUMNS`.

More comments on `PARTITIONing` (including the syntaxes above):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: for example above table is shared, actual id is uid string,

Comment: I have added the partition key(extra column) for every row to solve the problem. something like 2021111903(YYYYMMDDHH) format

Comment: @santhosh - A 36-char UUID?  That's bulky; what purpose does it serve?

Comment: And YYYYMMDDHH is bulky; a `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`) would be better.

Comment: but that doesn't provide us an option to create partition hourly

Comment: `BY RANGE(TO_SECONDS(datetime_col))` or `BY RANGE COLUMNS(datetime_col)`

Comment: ok will update accordingly, I think we can use to_seconds.

Comment: Rick can you help solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084973/mysql-to-handle-large-amount-of-data/70088307#70088307