# MySQL to handle large amount of data

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Currently, my application is generating around a 40million records every hour, I have created a partition for every hour so it will be easier for me to drop the partition as and when required, also using the partition to aggregate the data.

My aggregation procedure will run fine if there are not any queries happening but once those queries are started, the aggregation code takes more than an hour to complete.

in MySQL is there a process to freeze and not impact based on the queries happening to the database?

reply to @rick

- RAM: 32GB
- innodb_buffer_pool_size : 20GB
- SSD: Yes
- type of read: it's
  a mix of group by and update over primary key

I don't want to do aggregation for every 5 minutes, since that would also generate a large number of records and it's not achievable for application, I'm actually saving 5 partitions and running the oldest every hour, my application required a minimum of 5 hours of non-aggregated data.

for my application, no need for the ACID type of characteristics so changed the default isolation to READ-UNCOMMITTED, and auto-commit to 0 that improved the aggregation code running faster but inserts took a hit, which is taking more than 2s.

[image: query analyser update]

here updating the profile info for the aggregation query

```
+----------+-----+---------------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| QUERY_ID | SEQ | STATE                     | DURATION  | CPU_USER   | CPU_SYSTEM | CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY | CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY | BLOCK_OPS_IN | BLOCK_OPS_OUT | MESSAGES_SENT | MESSAGES_RECEIVED | PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR | PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR | SWAPS | SOURCE_FUNCTION       | SOURCE_FILE          | SOURCE_LINE |
+----------+-----+---------------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|    50754 |   2 | continuing inside routine |  0.000015 |   0.000197 |   0.000036 |                 1 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | NULL                  | NULL                 |        NULL |
|    50754 |   3 | checking permissions      |  0.000007 |   0.000005 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_authorization.cc |         809 |
|    50754 |   4 | checking permissions      |  0.000006 |   0.000006 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_authorization.cc |         809 |
|    50754 |   5 | Opening tables            |  0.000017 |   0.000013 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc          |        5815 |
|    50754 |   6 | init                      |  0.000260 |   0.000400 |   0.000073 |                 1 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | handle_query          | sql_select.cc        |         128 |
|    50754 |   7 | System lock               |  0.000011 |   0.000009 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc              |         330 |
|    50754 |   8 | optimizing                |  0.000115 |   0.000098 |   0.000017 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         158 |
|    50754 |   9 | statistics                |  0.001624 |   0.003051 |   0.000552 |                 3 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         374 |
|    50754 |  10 | preparing                 |  0.000158 |   0.000134 |   0.000024 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         482 |
|    50754 |  11 | Sorting result            |  0.000009 |   0.000007 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | make_tmp_tables_info  | sql_select.cc        |        3849 |
|    50754 |  12 | executing                 |  0.000006 |   0.000005 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc      |         126 |
|    50754 |  13 | Sending data              | 40.298694 | 144.161765 |  12.297466 |            596361 |              261826 |       265128 |       2899384 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |               328 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc      |         202 |
|    50754 |  14 | end                       |  0.000031 |   0.000024 |   0.000005 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | handle_query          | sql_select.cc        |         206 |
|    50754 |  15 | query end                 |  0.000016 |   0.000013 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        4959 |
|    50754 |  16 | closing tables            |  0.000055 |   0.000048 |   0.000007 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        5018 |
|    50754 |  17 | query end                 |  0.000007 |   0.000005 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        4959 |
|    50754 |  18 | closing tables            |  0.000012 |   0.000009 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        5018 |
+----------+-----+---------------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

aggregation code looks like this and each time takes around 100 clientKey around 100K clientKey available in each hour

```sql
insert into DB.NETWORK_USAGE_FINAL(clientKey,k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,createdAt)
            select clientKey, sum(k1) as k1, sum(k2) as k2, sum(k3) as k3 ,
            k4,  k5 , "',startTime,'" from DB.NETWORK_USAGE_F1 partition (',partitionKey,') 
            where clientKey in (',selectedClientKey,')
            group by clientKey,k4,k5
```

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=20
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=2M
innodb_log_file_size=3G
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
back_log = 1000
tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
join_buffer_size=1G
sort_buffer_size=512M
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
table_open_cache=4000
max_allowed_packet=1G
innodb_file_per_table=1
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
event_scheduler = ON
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking


key_buffer_size     = 1G
thread_stack        = 128M
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

show create table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `NETWORK_USAGE_F1` (
  `id` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `clientKey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `k4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `k5` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `partitionKey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `k1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `k2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `k3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`partitionKey`),
  KEY `key2` (`clientKey`,`k4`,`k5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (partitionKey)
 */
```

@reply to Rick updates:

- Aggregation code is running on 100 clientkey's(limit) at a time, for an hour there will be around 100K unique clientKey exists, but the overall number of rows in the DB is around 40 million rows for an hour/partition(so its nothing but each clientKey would have around 400 rows)
- id used is 15 character length only
- Currently, I have 5 partitions, the partition key is in the format of YYYYMMMDDHH
- Not using MyISAM

Comment: are you referring to the isolation level [REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) ? If your aggregation procedure is running it will not read the newly added data.

Comment: yes aggregation procedure will not be reading the newly added data

Comment: And what indexes are defined on the table `DB.NETWORK_USAGE_F1` ?

Comment: @Luuk updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the aggregation code.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Other things to try:

- Aggregate every 5 minutes instead.
- Aggregate "continually".  That is, do all the rows since you last did an aggregation.
- Collect the rows into a 'staging' table.  Then do the aggregation from that and finally copy the rows into the main table.  Here's a discussion of a "ping-pong" technique for such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

11K rows per second is a lot, but not impossible.

Further questions:

- How much RAM do you have?
- What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?
- Do you have SSD?
- What type of reads are going on at the same time?  (reading from big table?  reading from summary table?)

(re my.cnf)

I recommend you limit each of these to 1% of RAM (unless you have some identified reason for being larger):

```
tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
join_buffer_size=1G
sort_buffer_size=512M
max_allowed_packet=1G
key_buffer_size     = 1G    -- for MyISAM only
```

I hope you are not using MyISAM.  If not lower that one to 50M.

```
thread_stack        = 128M
```

Ouch!  Leave that at its default!

(Schema)

- Use `VARCHAR`, not `CHAR` unless the strings are truly fixed-length.
- Since your table will be huge, use the smallest practical `INT` size.
- How many `PARTITIONs` are there?  What version of MySQL?  ("Too many" partitions can, by itself, be a performance drag.)
- What is the `partitionkey` set to?

(other)

- Is "around 100 clientKey around 100K clientKey" a typo, or am I confused by what it is saying?
- Also, that seems to conflict with "40million records every hour".

Comment: Hi Rick, updated the question with your requirements, 
I can't follow the ping-pong technique since the application  requires 5 hours of non-aggregated data,

Comment: and great fan of your website and work, thanks for helping the community

Comment: @santhosh - Can you provide more details on the aggregation?  For example, one of my projects involved hourly aggregation, while having the raw data and 7 summary tables being kept for 90 days.

Comment: Hi Rick, updated the question with the details

Comment: @santhosh - I added a bunch.  I suspect I will have more to say later.

Comment: Hi Rick, observed one more thing if the overall DB size is less than RAM assigned aggregation is working fine, these changes are added based on the MySQL runner suggestions

```mysql
tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
join_buffer_size=1G
sort_buffer_size=512M
max_allowed_packet=1G```

Comment: @santhosh - Where is the typo?  Did MysqlTuner suggest 1G?  Or did it simply say "bigger"?  The issue is:  If too many connections simultaneously allocate 1GB for some of those, you could run out of RAM -- possibly causing a crash.

Comment: mysqltunner suggested the increment